# Batch script permissions issues

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, permissions, wireshark

I have a batch script written to auto start and capture traffic on a server for me but for some reason when I run it wireshark tells me it doesn't have permission to the folder where the script is trying to save the file. I have tried multiple different folders on and off the server I have tried giving everyone including SYSTEM full access to the folder. I have tried remaking the folder. I have tried running under and not under admin credentials I have tried letting the system task run it. Always get a permissions issue.

The weirdest part is if I run wireshark manually and save the data manually it has no permissions issues. Just if I run the script is the problem. Although they're both run under the same admin account.

Here is the script in case you need to see the flags I used.

```
@echo off

cd C:\Program Files\Wireshark
Wireshark.exe -i 4 -k -a duration:10 -w C:\Temp
pause
```

I did try to use a powershell script I had found online but it was pretty old and I couldn't get it to actually run. So any recommendations are welcome that include powershell or batch

Comment: What if you try putting the file in some other folder? `C:\Temp` has some special permissions associated with it, but you'll have better luck with a folder that you actually created yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Temp` isn't a file; it's a folder.  Try specifying an actual filename, like this:

```
@echo off

cd C:\Program Files\Wireshark
Wireshark.exe -i 4 -k -a duration:10 -w C:\Temp\foo.pcapng
pause
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue thank you. I swear I originally had a file name in there. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I really appreciate it.